# PHP: require doesn't work as it should

Tags: php

I have a directory root:

```
index.php
includes/
    template.php
    testfile.php
    phpFiles/
        processInput.php
        testfile.php
```

index.php:

```
require_once("includes/template.php");
```

template.php:

```
require_once("includes/phpFiles/processInput.php")
```

processInput.php:

```
require_once("testfile.php")
require_once("../testfile.php")
```

This code will work when you run index.php, of course it will not work when you run template.php.

As you can see, index.php includes template.php like normal. But in template.php, you have to include like if you are in the directory that index.php is in. But then, in processInput.php, you include as if you are in the directory that processInput.php is in.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it so that the include path is always the directory of the file that the require is done in? The second included file have the same include path as the requested file, but the next one does not.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: The strange thing is that I've included classes in a class folder. And it included other files as it is supposed to, even though the paths are relative. WHY does this happen, and how can I fix it?

VERY IMPORTANT EDIT: I just realized that all this is because in my example, the inclusion in includes/phpFiles/processInput.php includes a file in the same directory: require_once("file in same dir.php"); This is the reason. If you are including a file with out specifying anything more than the filename, the include_path is actually the dir where the file the require is written in is in. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a few ways, amongst others:

1. Use [`set_include_path`](http://www.php.net/set_include_path) to control the directories from where to perform `require()` calls.
2. Define a common absolute base path in a constant that you define in `index.php` and use that in every `require()` statement (e.g. `require(BASEPATH . '/includes/template.php')`).
3. Use relative paths everywhere and leverage `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` to turn them into absolute paths. For instance: `require(__DIR__ . '/phpFiles/processInput.php');`

By default, the current working directory is used in the include path; you can verify this by inspecting the output of `get_include_path()`. However, this is *not* relative to where the `include()` is made from; it's relative to the main executing script.

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts those classes you have seen probably leverage my point #3

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts updated my answer; basically, you've misunderstood the include system ;-)

Comment: So include_path is the include path of the main script only. :)

Answer (score 7):

Use an absolute path.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/phpFiles/processInput.php");
```

Use a similar form for all your `require`d files and they will work no matter where you are.

Comment: Yes, it will. I just want to be able to do it relatively. One reason is that it should be easily transferable.

Comment: The strange thing is that I've included classes in a class folder. And it included other files as it is supposed to, even though the paths are relative.

Comment: Since `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` always exists no matter what server you're on, there should be no problem. The only issue is if this is for some kind of app that is not in the document root, in which case you'll have to define a constant that tells the script where the root of your app is.

Answer (score 1):

You're using relative paths. You need to use absolute paths: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

When you include/require, you are basically temporarily moving all code from one file, to another.

so if **file1.php** (which is located in `root`) contains:

```
require("folder/file.php");
```

and you include **file1.php** in **file2.php** (which is in a different location (say `folder` directory for example):

**file2.php:**

```
require("../file1.php");
```

Now all of **file1.php** code is in **file2.php**. So **file2.php** will look like this:

```
require("../file1.php");
require("folder/file.php");//but because file2.php is already in the `folder` directory, this path does not exist...
```

Comment: Why do I need to use absolute paths?

Comment: You wrote: require("folder/file.php");//but because file2.php is already in the `folder` directory, this path does not exist...

Comment: But if you in file2.php include a file3.php, that file will not follow that rule. It will include the way I want it to do.

Comment: Why does it differentiate between using the mother-script-include-path and the current-script-include-path between include two and include three?

Answer (score 0):

index.php:

```
require_once("includes/template.php");
```

template.php:

```
require_once("includes/phpFiles/processInput.php")
```

Your directory structure is off.  The file inclusion is being seen from the file you're using it from.  So, "template.php" is looking for an "includes/" folder in *its* current folder (/includes/).

As others are saying, use absolute paths, which will make sure you're always going at it from the file system root, or use:

```
require_once("phpFiles/processInput.php")
```

In your template.php file (which is far more likely to break if you ever move things around, which is why others all recommend using absolute paths from the file system root).

BTW, if you're using "index.php" as some kind of framework system, you can consider defining a variable that stores the address of common files such as:

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
define('PHPFILES_PATH', APPLICAITON_PATH . '/includes/phpFiles/');
```